# Does aggregation/reporting of scoring across distinct but related SCORM packages usually fall under the remit of the containing LMS?

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2, articulate-storyline

I am designing an SCORMv1.2 based Elearning solution for a client who manage their existing training courses via SABA LMS. I am considering providing each section of the course as a separate SCO with its own score tracking.
I am wondering whether it is usually a function of the LMS to aggregate tracking scores across distinct SCO's for a user, or whether I should be creating multi-package SCO which aggregates scores for each of its child SCO's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there's a mix of some LMSs that will do some aggregation with scores and some that don't.

It's common practice for content vendors to deliver a complete block of content as a single package and often as a single SCO so that they can control the look and feel of the navigation. This means they often just present an aggregated score to the LMS.

It is possible to do more complex things with SCORM 2004 including multi-sco packages that include their own navigation menus, but this is not commonly done.

Here's some [statistics on what features of SCORM are commonly used](http://scorm.com/scorm-stats/?utm_source=scorm_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=scorm-stats?pmc=em-1).

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "Yes".  The vendor who publishes the content need to configure the each section of the course as a separate SCO so that they can be tracked separately in the LMS.

A SCORM 1.2 course can be delivered as multi SCO by using the parameters attribute of the item element in the manifest file.  This can also be acheived by using different start page for each SCO rather than one start page that is common for the entire course.